# How to make a correct pull request?

Tags: git, github

The remote repository has 3 branches: `master`, `dev`, `stage`

I need to add more features based on the remote `dev` branch and push it to the remote repository for review and make a pull request. What is the correct steps I need to do?

Is that...

1. `git clone <remote repository>`
2. `git branch -b feature-1 origin/dev`
3. On `feature-1` branch I add some codes…
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "add feature-1"`
6. `git push origin feature-1`

How can I make sure the pull request will be merged into the remote `dev` branch?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IDE (like VS), it is easier using the Git menu. Generally, when we develop a new feature, we follow that order.

Assumed that you cloned the project

- Pull (to be sure you get the latest changes)
- Make a new branch
- Switch to the new branch
- Make your changes
- Commit
- Push
- Make a PR on github

**Commands**

Make a new branch

```
git checkout -b {branch_name}
```

Commit

```
git add .

git commit -m {comment}
```

Push

```
git push -u origin {remote_branch_name}
```

From that point, you can make a new PR from github

Comment: Let’s say I have the dev branch on the remote repo, I need to add new features based on that remote dev branch. How can I create a new branch based on the remote dev branch?